# Caffe large files of type lmdb

Tags: computer-vision, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, lmdb

I'm wondering if there's a reason why lmdb files using in [caffe](/questions/tagged/caffe) are so much larger than the file containing the original images. Could you give me an explanation please?

Answer (score 5):

It is hard to give a concrete answer to such an abstract question, but I'll give it a try:
Image files are usually compressed: a `.png` or `.jpg` of size `h` by `w` by `3` takes far less disk space than `h*w*3` bytes due to compression. On the other hand, for processing the image in a neural network (or any other ML software for that matter) you need to work with the un-compressed representation of the image. Therefore, `lmdb`, `leveldb`, `hdf5` datasets used by caffe stores the input images in an **uncompressed** manner using 32bit float numbers for each pixels (instead of `uint8`) thus the drastic increase in file size.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I just want to  verify that this situation is usual and I didnt make any mistakes. Thank you Shai

Comment: @user5640428: Just in addition to this answer: **caffe** can work with compressed images stored in `lmdb`. If you use *convert_imageset* tool from **caffe**, you can pass `-encode_type=png` or `-encode_type=jpg` parameter to save encoded images to `lmdb`. It will significantly reduce your database size, but will take additional time in training/testing phase for decoding images.

Comment: @avtomaton , I would be interested in using this technique, since I am using a developer board with almost no memory , and need to use a USB stick to feed it the info.  Have you tried this before successfully? Also, would I have to add additional commands when running my net, or would caffe decode it by default?  Thanks

Comment: @jerpint This is an interesting question. why burry it in a comment? please consider post it as a question

Comment: @Shai I have posted a question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37661134/compressing-lmdb-files) , thanks