# Compressing LMDB files

Tags: compression, jpeg, caffe, lmdb

I am wondering if anyone has tried using compression techniques for their LMDB files?  Typically, lmdb files typically do not use any compression. I am wondering if anyone has successfully stored data in an lmdb using jpeg compression on lmdb and then used it for caffe.  I need this because I am working on a developer board with very limited storage space.  If so, can you please provide steps/code to do this?

thanks

Comment: have you considered using `--encoded_type jpg` in [`convert_imageset`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31427094/guide-to-use-convert-imageset-cpp)?

Comment: I am considering it, just wondering if anyone has experience using it, and if I need an extra decode step afterwards

Comment: afaik, you do not need anything special afterwards

Comment: ok thank you @Shai, if i go down that route i will update this post

Answer (score 1):

Caffe also supports HDF5 which supports compression. If your dataset is smth like mnist - it may be a good choice.